# One line serial communication, echos wrong

Tags: c, ubuntu, serial-port, termios

I have a one line serial communication interface, and the problem is that I send in 01010101 and the echo that I receive is 8 out of 10 times 01010101 but 2 out of 10 I receive 01110101.

Code example:

```
void checkVersion(int fd) {
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    unsigned char checkVersion[] = {0x55, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02};
    int n = write(fd, &checkVersion, 4); //Send data
    if (n < 0) cout << "BM: WRITE FAILED" << endl;

    char read_bytes[10] = {0};
    char c;
    int aantalBytes = 0;
    bool foundU = false;
    int res;
    while (aantalBytes < 7) {
        res = read(fd, &c, 200);
        if (res != 0) {
            cout << "Byte received: " << bitset < 8 > (c) << endl;
            if (c == 'U')foundU = true;
            if (foundU)
                read_bytes[aantalBytes++] = c;
        }
        if (aantalBytes > 2 && !foundU) break;
    }
    if (!foundU) checkVersionSucceeded = false;
    if (read_bytes[aantalBytes - 3] == 0x02 && read_bytes[aantalBytes - 2] == 0x04 && read_bytes[aantalBytes - 1] == 0x06)
       cout << "BM Version 4" << endl;
}
```

How I configure my port:

```
int configure_port(int fd) // configure the port
{
    struct termios port_settings; // structure to store the port settings in

    cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B9600); // set baud rates
    cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B9600);

    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // set no parity, stop bits, data bits
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    port_settings.c_cflag |= CS8;

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings); // apply the settings to the port
    return (fd);
}
```

What is the problem? How is it possible that the echo is mixed up 2 out 10 times?

Comment: What are you communicating with?  How is it configured?

Comment: Maybe you should fix the following:
char c; ...
res = read(fd, &c, 200);   It may cause overflow. And that can cause nasty problems.

Comment: `res = read(fd, &c, 200);` You attempt to read 200 bytes into a one-byte character?

Comment: As @wildplasser already illustrated, your code has a few quirks. E.g. it also looks like you wanted to hunt for the 'U' character in the first 7 bytes, but `aantalBytes` is only incremented if an 'U' is found.  The `if (!foundU) {}` statement is useless because the loop won't exit without `foundU` being `true`. Maybe try doing something realy simple first like `tcflush();write(1 char);read(1 char);` and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but not solved yet. I am indeed 'hunting' for the U because that is what I'm sending in as first byte (0x55 = U) and therefore should be received as first byte, everything before the U (if there is any) is garbage. The loop won't exit if it fails indeed, in the real function I have a 'loop killer counter'.

Comment: @Bart With only tcflush();write(1 char);read(1 char); I have the same problem. Could it be that 0x55 is not interpreted as 01010101?

Comment: 0x55 is not wrongly interpreted. The checkVersion array sends 01010101 but the first read byte is 01110101

Comment: The difference is 32, which also happens to be the difference between 'U' and 'u', in ASCII ...

Comment: If you try to read 200 bytes into a one byte array, then all bets are off until you fix it. You could be overwriting your whole program data with junk, putting your program in la-la-land, giving any random output and behavior.

Comment: Anyway, you should check for buffer overruns and other UART errors. If you get UART errors, the problem is related to UART settings. Otherwise, it is in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should try the function bzero() when you configure the connection.

```
bzero(&port_settings, sizeof (port_settings));
```

This clears the struct for new port settings, which might help to stop the irregular answers you receive over the serial port.